# feh image viewer in thumbnail mode want scrollable window

Tags: feh

If I go `feh --thumbnails <directory>` I get a nice clickable screen of thumbnails for the images in `<directory>`.

But

- I can't scroll that screen
- If I close an image I raise, the thumbnail display closes too.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the controls listed in the docs [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/feh#:%7E:text=the%20following%20keys%20may%20be%20used), they're not intuitive but they work on mine.

- Click and drag: scroll
- Ctrl+Up/ Ctrl+Down: scroll
- x: close image window, return to thumbnails
- Up/Down: zoom in and out on thumbnails